# What is % in regular expression "%^/(test)-(.*?)-(.*?)$%"?

Tags: magento-2.1, regex

I am doing magento2 developer training. I am working on exercise"Create a new router which “understands” URLs like /frontNameactionPath-
action and converts them to /frontName/actionPath/action". In that exercise I come across the code

```
if (preg_match("%^/(test)-(.*?)-(.*?)$%", $info, $m)) {
    $request->setPathInfo(sprintf("/%s/%s/%s", $m[1], $m[2], $m[3]));
    return $this->actionFactory->create('Magento\Framework\App\Action\Forward',
    ['request' => $request]);
}
```

I want to know, What is % in regular expression "%^/(test)-(.*?)-(.*?)$%"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are just the [delimiters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Delimiters) on the regular expression and not part of the expression itself. My thinking is they used `%` and not the normal `/` so that the `/` in the regex itself would not have to be escaped.

Comment: Why this delimiter used? is this optional?

Comment: @PMB I think they picked `%` over the "normal" `/` so as to avoid having to escape the `/` inside the expression itself.